# UICollectionView showing cells with multiple sizes?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a `UICollectionView` in my storyboard which has a `UICollectionViewCell` of which I have clicked and dragged to make its size 100w 100h. I also have a swift file controlling this. The code is as follows:

```
override func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    //#warning Incomplete method implementation -- Return the number of sections
    return 4
}


override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    //#warning Incomplete method implementation -- Return the number of items in the section
    return 10
}

override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UICollectionViewCell

    // Configure the cell

    return cell
}
```

When I run this however, the first row is stretched like this: [image]

How to I get them all to be the same size?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is not a "stretched" first row cell. It is a section inset of 0 points, which causes the last cell of section 0 to be flush up against the first cell of section 1.

You can fix this issue by implementing `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` and setting the section inset. Make your class conform to `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`, set `collectionView.delegate` to `self`, and  implement the desired functions of `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`. Relevant delegate functions include:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> CGFloat
```